# Change Images on Custom CheckBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

All I have created the following custom `CheckBox` which uses images instead of a `CheckBox`. This works well however, I want to be able to change the images as required. Ideally I would like to use application resources `Properties.Resources.SomeImage16` (a .png file). The XAML is

```
<Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" 
       TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="imageCheckBox" 
                           Width="16" 
                           Height="16" 
                           Source="F:\Camus\ResourceStudio\Graphics\Images\UnPinned16.png"/>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" 
                                Property="Source" 
                                Value="F:\Camus\ResourceStudio\Graphics\Images\Pinned16.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" 
                                Property="Source"
                                Value="F:\Camus\ResourceStudio\Graphics\Images\UnPinned16.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With implementation

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="4,0,4,0"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Text="SomeRecentDocument.resx"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

**How can I change the images used for the custom `CheckBox` (i.e. change the pinned/un-pinned to tick/cross etc.) without having to create a new style/template?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1 - Dont use PNGs for everything. WPF is not winforms. Use Vector graphics whenever possible. 2 - You may want to create some `Attached Properties` and bind to that in the `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: If that was allowed then a .NET application would have access to any drive.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... is it about changing the image based on the checkbox state? If so using triggers would work but you already have some triggers there... is it that the solution you tried is not working and you need help getting it to work?

Comment: @DeanK. I have a working custom check box control with images as pinned/unpinned. I want to know how/if it is possible to change the images for these states when I use the control...

Comment: @HighCore how can I get a vector image from my Expression Design .design files? I can export to XAML, but the exported results for some images are complex and made of many layers...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As already mentioned `@HighCore` the need for the ability to use vector graphics. In this case, to use the `Path`, where in `Data` to the specified coordinates on which the object is drawn ([`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx)).

Advantages:

- Do not store it in the files, smaller size
- Dynamically changing color, size and the whole shape

Minuses (in my opinion):

- You can not always find the right `Data` for the `Path`

About minus: There are special sites ([www.modernuiicons.com](http://modernuiicons.com/)) and utilities for converting the image to `Data`.

Change the style of `CheckBox` using the `Path`:

`Style`

```
<Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Path x:Name="MyPin" Width="18" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000"
                              Data="F1 M 56.1355,32.5475L 43.4466,19.8526C 42.7886,20.4988 42.298,21.2123 41.9749,21.9932C 41.6519,22.7741 41.4903,23.5729 41.4903,24.3895C 41.4903,25.1942 41.6529,25.987 41.9779,26.7679L 34.0577,34.6821C 33.3918,34.3372 32.6991,34.0776 31.9796,33.9032C 31.2601,33.7288 30.5298,33.6415 29.7885,33.6415C 28.623,33.6415 27.4953,33.8526 26.4052,34.2748C 25.315,34.697 24.3419,35.3342 23.4856,36.1865L 30.2344,42.9174L 25.9027,47.9032L 22.6532,51.8425L 20.5988,54.5836C 20.1212,55.2892 19.8823,55.753 19.8823,55.975L 19.8645,56.0701L 19.9002,56.088L 19.9002,56.1474L 19.9358,56.1058L 20.0131,56.1236C 20.2351,56.1236 20.6989,55.8888 21.4045,55.419L 24.1457,53.3765L 28.0849,50.1151L 33.0945,45.7775L 39.8016,52.5025C 40.6579,51.6462 41.2961,50.6731 41.7163,49.5829C 42.1365,48.4928 42.3466,47.367 42.3466,46.2056C 42.3466,45.4603 42.2603,44.729 42.0879,44.0115C 41.9155,43.294 41.6548,42.6003 41.3069,41.9304L 49.2202,34.0161C 50.0011,34.3372 50.7939,34.4978 51.5986,34.4978C 52.4192,34.4978 53.2189,34.3362 53.9979,34.0132C 54.7768,33.6901 55.4894,33.2015 56.1355,32.5475 Z "/>

                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="MyPin" Property="Data" Value="F1 M 32.3691,30.2225L 33.2253,29.3901L 15.361,11.5258C 13.9814,12.7067 12.6951,13.9936 11.5148,15.3738L 26.6252,30.4842C 27.743,30.1631 28.8767,30.0025 30.0263,30.0025C 30.8191,30.0025 31.6,30.0759 32.3691,30.2225 Z M 45.5039,49.3629L 60.6292,64.4826C 62.0123,63.2996 63.3017,62.0101 64.4846,60.6268L 46.6218,42.7866L 45.7834,43.619L 45.9439,44.7726L 45.9915,45.9261L 45.8785,47.6713L 45.5039,49.3629 Z M 56.1355,32.5475L 43.4466,19.8526C 42.7886,20.4987 42.298,21.2123 41.9749,21.9932C 41.6519,22.7741 41.4903,23.5729 41.4903,24.3895C 41.4903,25.1942 41.6529,25.987 41.9779,26.7679L 34.0577,34.6821C 33.3918,34.3372 32.6991,34.0776 31.9796,33.9032C 31.2601,33.7288 30.5298,33.6415 29.7885,33.6415C 28.623,33.6415 27.4953,33.8526 26.4052,34.2748C 25.315,34.697 24.3419,35.3342 23.4856,36.1865L 30.2344,42.9174L 25.9027,47.9032L 22.6532,51.8425L 20.5988,54.5836C 20.1212,55.2892 19.8823,55.753 19.8823,55.975L 19.8645,56.0701L 19.9002,56.0879L 19.9002,56.1474L 19.9358,56.1058L 20.0131,56.1236C 20.2351,56.1236 20.6989,55.8888 21.4045,55.419L 24.1457,53.3765L 28.0849,50.1151L 33.0945,45.7775L 39.8016,52.5025C 40.6579,51.6462 41.2961,50.6731 41.7163,49.5829C 42.1365,48.4928 42.3466,47.367 42.3466,46.2056C 42.3466,45.4603 42.2603,44.729 42.0879,44.0115C 41.9155,43.294 41.6548,42.6003 41.306,41.9304L 49.2202,34.0161C 50.0011,34.3372 50.7939,34.4978 51.5986,34.4978C 52.4192,34.4978 53.219,34.3362 53.9979,34.0132C 54.7768,33.6901 55.4894,33.2015 56.1355,32.5475 Z " />                                
                            <Setter TargetName="MyPin" Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

`Using`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox Height="35"
              Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
              Content="MySolution1" />

    <CheckBox Height="35"
              Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
              Content="MySolution2" />
</StackPanel>
```

`Output`

[image]

We can also store the `Path's` in resources, and refer to them as like this:

```
<Path x:Key="MyPath" Data="F1 M 38,19C 48.4934,19 57,27.5066 ... />

...

<Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Data"
        Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyPath}, Path=Data}" />
```

**`Edit`**

To specify arbitrary icons, I created two attached dependency properties (string type):

- IsCheckedOnData
- IsCheckedOffData

`IsCheckedOnData` contains `Data` value by `IsChecked = "True"`, `IsCheckedOffData` value  by `IsChecked = "False"`.

Now you need only to determine the strings of icons and define such a resource (for example).

Full example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="CustomCheckBoxHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomCheckBoxHelp"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="Up">
        F1 M 37.8516,35.625L 34.6849,38.7917L 23.6016,50.2708L 
        23.6016,39.9792L 37.8516,24.9375L 52.1016,39.9792L 52.1016,
        50.2708L 41.0182,38.7917L 37.8516,35.625 Z
    </sys:String>

    <sys:String x:Key="Down">
        F1 M 37.8516,39.5833L 52.1016,24.9375L 52.1016,35.2292L 
        37.8516,50.2708L 23.6016,35.2292L 23.6016,24.9375L 37.8516,39.5833 Z
    </sys:String>

    <Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Path x:Name="MyPin" Width="18" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" 
                              Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:CustomCheckBoxClass.IsCheckedOnData)}" />
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="MyPin" Property="Data"
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:CustomCheckBoxClass.IsCheckedOffData)}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="MyPin" Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Beige">
        <CheckBox Height="35" 
                  local:CustomCheckBoxClass.IsCheckedOnData="{StaticResource Up}"
                  local:CustomCheckBoxClass.IsCheckedOffData="{StaticResource Down}"
                  Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
                  Content="MySolution1" />

        <CheckBox Height="35" 
                  local:CustomCheckBoxClass.IsCheckedOnData="{StaticResource Up}"
                  local:CustomCheckBoxClass.IsCheckedOffData="{StaticResource Down}"
                  Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
                  Content="MySolution2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
}

public class CustomCheckBoxClass : DependencyObject
{
    #region IsCheckedOnDataProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedOnDataProperty;

    public static void SetIsCheckedOnData(DependencyObject DepObject, string value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(IsCheckedOnDataProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetIsCheckedOnData(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (string)DepObject.GetValue(IsCheckedOnDataProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IsCheckedOffDataProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedOffDataProperty;

    public static void SetIsCheckedOffData(DependencyObject DepObject, string value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(IsCheckedOffDataProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetIsCheckedOffData(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (string)DepObject.GetValue(IsCheckedOffDataProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    static CustomCheckBoxClass()
    {
        PropertyMetadata MyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty);

        IsCheckedOnDataProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCheckedOnData",
                                                            typeof(string),
                                                            typeof(CustomCheckBoxClass),
                                                            MyPropertyMetadata);

        IsCheckedOffDataProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCheckedOffData",
                                                            typeof(string),
                                                            typeof(CustomCheckBoxClass),
                                                            MyPropertyMetadata);
    }        
}
```

`Note:` In the style I have not used `TemplateBinding` because `TemplateBinding` doesn’t work outside a template or outside its VisualTree property, so you can’t even use `TemplateBinding` inside a template’s trigger. Therefore, we must use the construction `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` and a `Path` equal to the dependency property whose value you want to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. It seems odd to use such an extensive string for the images data. If this really is the standard way, then so be it. I have all my own icons designed in Expression design, so I will look into a conversion utility... I wanted to know though, how to change the actual image for the custom check box - so say if I wanted to display ticks and crosses instead, how can this be done with out creating another style - or is this not possible?

Comment: @Killercam, The best practice would be to keep this vector image data in a separate resource file instead of the local resource.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I would like to reference more complex vector graphics from a resource file. Can you take a look at this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541408/how-to-reference-a-vectored-graphic-in-control-binding?noredirect=1#comment27272770_18541408

Comment: @Killercam: Yes, now look.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't yet know how to reference an image in those resources, but if you can add the images into a folder named `Images` in your application root directory, then you will be able to reference the images simply like this:

```
<Image Source="/ApplicationName;component/Images/SomeImage16.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you can change the checkbox trigger by checked and unchecked. And the image will display corresponding trigger. Your xml code is good for me.I just remove the trigger true portion.because the false portion by default in focus and after click the checkbox image UnPinned16.png is visible. And agan click image Pinned16.png is visibale .

```
<Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" 
       TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="imageCheckBox" 
                           Width="16" 
                           Height="16" Source="F:\Camus\ResourceStudio\Graphics\Images\UnPinned16.png"/>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" 
                                Property="Source" 
                                Value="F:\Camus\ResourceStudio\Graphics\Images\Pinned16.png"/>
                    </Trigger>                        
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I am using this checkbox under a textblock

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="4,0,4,0"/>
```